# How do we know the Christoffel symbols can be defined this way?

Tags: differential-geometry, differentiation

I am reading [this article](http://www.physicspages.com/2013/12/22/christoffel-symbols-in-terms-of-the-metric-tensor/) and they say one definition of the Christoffel symbols is

$$\partial_j e_i = \Gamma_{ij}^k e_k.$$

Here $(e_i)$ denotes the basis vectors for a coordinate system, and this is saying the (covariant) derivative of a basis vector with respect to coordinate $x^j$ can be equal to a linear combination of the same basis vectors with constant terms called Christoffel symbols.

I am just wondering, you can't actually do this in every setting right? I mean the derivative of an object lives in the tangent space and that is an object in a different space, how do we know it can be written as a linear combination of the original basis vectors? (In local coordinates -> flat space -> Euclidean space -> regular differentiation, nothing strange occurs because it follows calculus differentiation.)

Comment: It would clarify if you wrote both $\partial$ and  $\nabla$ then realized there is no explicit coordinate dependence for this vector field in this coordinate patch. Hence one term drops to 0.

Comment: @AHusain, could elaborate? I m not sure how this is related to my question

Comment: Write the general form of a covariance derivative. You see two pieces. In this case one piece is 0 turning into your equation above.

Comment: @AHusain, well normally one uses the expression I stated to get to the covariant derivative. That's circular?

Comment: Oh your using this to define the connection rather than doing it intrinsically. Look at other definitions.

Comment: @AHusain, kinda defeats the point of this question...

Comment: The better definition is via the frame bundle.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as though you may be getting a little confused by the fact that in Euclidean / Minkowskian space, one can think of "position vectors" defining points in the differentiable manifold itself.

But in the general setting, the notion of "vector" and "tensor" are *only* be defined in the tangent spaces to a given point. The manifold's points themselves cannot be thought of as vectors.

In the general setting, the tangent space to a point $p\in M$ in a differentiable manifold $M$ can be thought of as the space of derivatives $\mathrm{d}_\lambda \phi(\sigma(\lambda))|_{\lambda=0}$ of scalar functions $\phi:M\to\mathbb{R}$ of the points along $C^1$ paths $\sigma:[-1,\,1]\to M$ through that point (*i.e.* the path $\sigma$ passes through the point $p$ at $\lambda=0$). This space is a vector or linear space in the mathematical sense of the word: *i.e.* as decomposable into a linear superposition of *basis vectors* $e_i = \mathrm{d}_\lambda \phi(\zeta_i(\lambda))|_{\lambda=0}$.

Now, when we discuss the notion of a *covariant derivative* and the associated notion of *parallel transport* this latter notion is, [*by definition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_derivative#Formal_definition), the notion of a map *between* tangent spaces to neighboring points in the manifold that is linear. When the notion is incorporated into the covariant derivative the latter object must fulfill Leibnitz's rule.

So the formula you cite is simply an expression of the linearity axiom of the definition: the image of the superposition of basis vectors is the superposition of the images of the individual basis vectors, *i.e.* what your formula is telling you.

Comment: Sorry the last sentence is too hard for me to understand, but from what I am understanding. Basically the equation I wrote down is in local coordinates in Euclidean Space (that's the definition for charts). I agree that for some reason I thought we were on the manifold.

Comment: @jacobsmith I'm simply saying that this follows directly from the definition of the covariant derivative, in particular from the linearity axiom. Have a look at the sections I linked on the Wiki page.